# Setting up magento site in sub domain

Tags: magento, dns, subdomain

i have a magento site main domain.

i did the following steps :

```
1.Downloaded the full magento site from main domain(mydomain.com)
2.Created a sub domain as new.mydomain.com(in plesk)
3.Uploaded the full magento site in to sub domain.
4.Created new database and imported the database.
5.Changed the secure url and unsecure url as 'http://www.new.mydomain.com/' in core_config_table.
6.Changed the local.xml file with new database details.
```

The above steps i did.

Then i take the sub domain as new.mydomain.com in browser, but it goes to main domain(mydomain.com).

What is the reason for that?

I contacted the client, the client give me the information that, there is no server problem. It is in your code.

So what is the problem here?

Is there is any redirection to main domain from sub domain?

Or is there is any file taken from main domain instead of sub domain?

How can i solve this?

Are there any additional steps here i need to do?

I already checked the index.php page:

Here, i give an echo statement before `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);`
that is :

`echo "test";
die();
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType`

Then the `test` will be displayed.

So when running `mage` it redirects to main domain.

Comment: Have you tried changing the base url in admin panel? 

See Step 12 in [this link](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/magento/getting-started-tutorial/how-to-install-magento)

Comment: @Ozair Kafray, the admin panel of sub domain cannot be access now

Comment: @Ozair Kafray, the link given you described fresh installation of magento.But in my case the magento already installed in main domain.I just downlaoded it from main and put it in sub domain.And did the above 4 steps

Answer (score 1):

fwiw:  magento stores the "domain" information in at least two records in the core_config_data table:

mysql> select * from core_config_data where value like '%mydomain.com/';
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                  | value                |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+----------------------+
|         4 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_url | http://mydomain.com/ |
|         5 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_url   | http://mydomain.com/ |
|      1488 | stores  |        2 | web/unsecure/base_url | http://mydomain.com/ |
|      1489 | stores  |        2 | web/secure/base_url   | http://mydomain.com/ |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+----------------------+

Before making the backup of the database, or even after backing it up, but before attempting to make the new site live, run an update statement:

update core_config_data set value = 'http://mynewdomain.com' where value = 'http://mydomain.com'

And then the site should come up fine.

Another method is to change the secure and the unsecure urls in the System->Configuration->web section and then saving the database.

SS

Answer (score 0):

Have you clean cache ? ( removing /var/cache dir ) ?

You can try by phpmyadmin searching for mydomain.com in all the database and change it.

Comment: how can i search in all the databse?

Comment: 1. open phpmyadmin interface  
  2. select magento db

  3. select search 

you should have something like this [link](http://www.matthewtaylor.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/_d_improd_/phpmyadmin-search-database_f_improf_492x234.jpg)

Comment: how can i find the text `mydomain.com` and replace it with subdomain in the database?

Comment: yes chaned with new sub domian name.it again goes to main domain

Comment: please crosscheck that you have changed all rows that contains mydomain.com ... 
and try to clean also browser cache ( or use incognito/private mode )


I found out this discussion regarding a similar problem ([link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/18660/#t69371))


Really don't know how help you more and I know how this issue could be annoying ...